# Issue to installing module in Thonny (Python text editor)

Tags: python, python-module, adafruit-circuitpython, thonny

I downloaded Thonny (which is a text editor for python) for using my Raspberry Pi Pico, and I tried to install a module in *"Manage packages"*, when I began the installation, this error line code appeared:

```
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'
Process returned with code 1
```

Fortunately there is another way to install modules and I tried it:

*Install from a local file*: I installed the package in cmd `pip install Adafruit-SSD1306` in target directory of the Thonny's modules `C:\Users\33631\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages`, but I still don't see the module I installed.

After that, I figured out I can't install modules at all, and it brings me the same error message.

[image: Here is the error]

I use:

- Python version: 3.10
- Pip version: 22.3
- Thonny version: 4.0.1

I tried many things, change the directory, install with the cmd and research with the *Install from a local file*, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I use also the **Thonny editor** several years, but have never used his `Tool | Manage packages...` function. I use always `pip install ...` instead.

If you open this dialog, it shows you a **Target** path something like *C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages*, depending on your phython version and path. I assume that python packages are installed always under the phython directory like `C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages`. My **Thonny editor** is olso there. Have you searched into python site-packages directory, too?